# How can l edit the frontend login form in revo wordpress theme while logged into wordpress as admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I installed revo theme on wordpress and also installed woocommerce, woocommerce multivendor plugins. l have an admin account and a customer account. when l try to customize the login form in the theme while logged in as admin it displays a customer dashboard instead of a form. How can I edit the login form in the theme?

when am not logged into the frontend/backend this is what I see
[image]

[image]

When I log in as admin and what to edit the login page as shown in the second image the fourth image is the screen I see

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking... can you complete your question with some screenshot?

Comment: I'd suggest opening a private (incognito) window and edit it there

Comment: @DanieleFois please find screen shoots attached. l just want to edit the login form in the theme frontend while logged in as admin.it shows the frontend dashboard(customer dashboard) when instead.

Comment: @boylett .that is the answer..thanks